# OpenCart RESTful API for Android Application

Tags: php, android, rest, opencart

I am new to OpenCart, and in process of creating OpenCart RESTful APIs for an android application. Now I have created an API which would login the customer. No issue. But I don't know how can I handle session cart for each customer who is logged in through android app.

Is there any Token maintained by OpenCart or any cart session variable which I can use.

I saw somewhere in source "$this->session->data['cart']" but couldn't understand its function properly.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Are you asking about how the "$this->session->data['cart']" works or what?

Comment: Referring, to my original question, I was asking that if this session variable could help me to identify the specific android user's cart. Or do I have any other way to add/remove products from each user's individual cart?

Comment: the session variable **won't help** you to do it, you have to add/remove products from the cart manually but make sure that you do it exactly the same as OC do it, the easiest way is to include the file `<OC_ROOT>/system/library/cart.php&lt;` in your webservice and use the class `Cart` directly

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have gone through to the Cart class "system/library/cart.php". What I understand is that it is adding/removing products from the session variable $this->session->data['cart'] and not dealing with the database. Please, as I am new to OC, an example would be very useful for me at this level. Thanks

Comment: opencart can provide API for its website. you can develop android application using that API. "$this->session->data['cart']" I thought this is modify functionality. I would suggest contus M Comm. It is an readymade solution & 100% customization, you can develop your opencart android application instantly. Just visit once